# gatsby sass is not working --import error

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I have tried to use gatsby-plugin-sass on my site, but there is a funny error happening see below.

```
warn Attempted import error: './header.module.scss' does not contain a default export (imported as 'headerStyles').
```

I have a `header.module.scss` and the `header.js` which contains:

```
import {Link} from "gatsby"

import headerStyles from "./header.module.scss"

const Header = () => {
    return(
        <header>
            <h1>NetoSena</h1>
            <nav className={headerStyles.nav}>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/blog">Blog</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    )
}

export default Header
```

So I don't know what to do please someone culd help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import it like:

```
import {Link} from "gatsby"

import * as headerStyles from "./header.module.scss"

const Header = () => {
    return(
        <header>
            <h1>NetoSena</h1>
            <nav className={headerStyles.nav}>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/contact">Contact</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/blog">Blog</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    )
}

export default Header
```

This is because of the new Gatsby module importation.

You can follow the stack trace of the discussion in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/30040).

Comment: It's not a bug, it’s working as intended: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/migrating-from-v2-to-v3/#css-modules-are-imported-as-es-modules

Comment: f yea.  quickest solution hunt I have ever done.  Thank you